# How to handle timeout in Requests properly

Tags: python, python-requests

As for now I use Requests as follows:

```
for url in urls:
  req1 = requests.request("GET", url, timeout=5)
  req2 = requests.request("POST", url, data=foo(req1.text), timeout=5)
```

The problem is that as a result of slow connection, the request hangs frequently, causing the process to get stuck and throw the ConnectionClosed exception after max retries reached.

Based on the demand, it is not necessary that each url gets processed correctly, which means as long as most of the urls are processed, some can be skipped if the connection failed.

So I wrap the code above with a try...except... block:

```
for url in urls:
  try:
    req1 = requests.request("GET", url, timeout=5)
    req2 = requests.request("POST", url, data=foo(req1.text), timeout=5)
  except:
    time.sleep(120)
    continue
```

Now the problem is that while the urls can be iterated over theoretically, only some can be processed. In fact, after the first exception thrown, all the subsequent requests tend to suffer from the same connection problem, that is, the process actually falls into endless "time.sleep()".

However, if I restart the script when the exception gets thrown, the connection problem won't persist, at least it can run smoothly for plenty of time.

I guess there must be some mechanism ignored by me, but I'm not so sure. Is there any connection reuse that gets in the way? In that case, how should I reset the connection upon exception? Should I use session which closes after each iteration? In that case, how can I achieve decent efficiency?

Thanks in advance.

Related post: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/520